# Uncaught DOMException while using Opencv

Tags: javascript, html, image, web-applications, cvzone

I have been trying to deploy my computer vision project on web, but when using OpenCV package for showing up the image through JavaScript file, it prompts an error

```
Uncaught DOMException DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
    at Module.imread (c:\Users\tonya\Projects\Cvzone_web_app\Resources\opencv.js:30:9105348)
    at cv.onRuntimeInitialized (c:\Users\tonya\Projects\Cvzone_web_app\Module_A_Introduction\1_template\main.js:5:26)
    at doRun (c:\Users\tonya\Projects\Cvzone_web_app\Resources\opencv.js:30:9104302)
    at run (c:\Users\tonya\Projects\Cvzone_web_app\Resources\opencv.js:30:9104462)
    at runCaller (c:\Users\tonya\Projects\Cvzone_web_app\Resources\opencv.js:30:9103961)
    at removeRunDependency (c:\Users\tonya\Projects\Cvzone_web_app\Resources\opencv.js:30:14897)
    at receiveInstance (c:\Users\tonya\Projects\Cvzone_web_app\Resources\opencv.js:30:8907244)
    at receiveInstantiatedSource (c:\Users\tonya\Projects\Cvzone_web_app\Resources\opencv.js:30:8907364)
    --- Promise.then ---
    at instantiateArrayBuffer (c:\Users\tonya\Projects\Cvzone_web_app\Resources\opencv.js:30:8907536)
    at instantiateAsync (c:\Users\tonya\Projects\Cvzone_web_app\Resources\opencv.js:30:8908146)
    at createWasm (c:\Users\tonya\Projects\Cvzone_web_app\Resources\opencv.js:30:8908390)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\tonya\Projects\Cvzone_web_app\Resources\opencv.js:30:9069105)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\tonya\Projects\Cvzone_web_app\Resources\opencv.js:46:10)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\tonya\Projects\Cvzone_web_app\Resources\opencv.js:14:15)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\tonya\Projects\Cvzone_web_app\Resources\opencv.js:22:2)
```

This is the JavaScript file that I'm working on.

```
function openCvReady() {
    cv["onRuntimeInitialized"] = () => {
        console.log("OpenCv Ready")
        // read an image from the image source and convert to opencv format
        let imgMain = cv.imread("img-main"); // image in opencv mat format
        cv.imshow("main-canvas", imgMain);
        imgMain.delete(); // to free the memory allocated
    }
}
```

If anyone have come across this issue, kindly please let me know to get rid of it.

I need to get rid of this error at first, so that I could integrate my webcam for further processes. Error: Uncaught DOMException DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.

Comment: please contact "cvzone".